# Can a Google apps CacheService instance be shared between two scripts bounded documents?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to be able to access cached key,values pairs from a different spreadsheet than the one that puts the values in.
Is that possible and if yes, in which context?

Thx for your answers.
Berni

Comment: The script with the values to be retrieved would need to publish the project as a stand alone Apps Script Web App using Content Service.  Then the script to retrieve the values would need to make an HTTPS GET request to the first script with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`.  There is no "built-in" way to access the cache of one project from another project.  You would also, probably need to use OAuth2 to authorize getting the data from the script with the cache.

Comment: You can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33447294/1677912) for a similar sharing scenario involving Properties.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. I then guess that I should take the Cache management out of my first Spreadsheet to make it a standalone Library that both Spreadsheet will use via Fetch requests in order to read and write the same Cache instance.